# Maven Tycho Plugin and Eclipse Babel

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin

How can I use `Maven Tycho Plugin` with `Eclipse Babel`? I didn't find information about it.

Comment: Can you describe your Problem? Do you want translated maven output?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't answer you. 

I required use localization for standart SWT message in my program. But I didn't find how use babel with maven.

Answer (score 2):

Now I find solution. For that require simple add babel repository in pom file. For example:

```
<repository>
    <id>p2-babel</id>
    <layout>p2</layout>
    <url>http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.11.1/kepler</url>
</repository>
```

and add to file .product necessary locale library from babel.