# Where can I find org.eclipse.jface.nl_de?

Tags: java, maven, rcp, tycho

I'm having a hard time to get an RCP aplication compiling with maven using tycho.

My `feature.xml` file contains this dependency:

```
<plugin
     id="org.eclipse.jface.nl_de"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="0.0.0"
     fragment="true"
     unpack="false"/>
```

When I do a `mvn clean install` I keep getting the error message listed below. It seams that maven does not know where to get org.eclipse.jface.nl_de.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

I'm using Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) and JDK 1.7 on a win7 box.

```
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] {osgi.ws=win32, osgi.os=win32, osgi.arch=x86, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 requires 'org.eclipse.jface.nl_de 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.jface.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.swt.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.workbench.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.help.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.jface.databinding.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.browser.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.views.nl_de 0.0.0.", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.jface.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.swt.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.workbench.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.help.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.jface.databinding.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.browser.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.views.nl_de 0.0.0.", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.jface.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.swt.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.workbench.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.help.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.jface.databinding.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.browser.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.nl_de 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.company.mct.pw.client.feature.feature.group 8.0.0 to org.eclipse.ui.views.nl_de 0.0.0.", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        ... 11 more
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22171167/2670892

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need it but you can get the file (and almost ANY language pack plugin fragment) from BABEL Eclipse Project: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/babel/update-site/R0.13.1/babel-R0.13.1-kepler.zip&mirror_id=491
Just download the ZIP and get the plugin from the plugins directory.